# How to get Java MANIFEST.MF to include Maven Version Number

Tags: java, maven, version, manifest

I have the following in my project's pom.xml which I think should display the version of Maven being used in the resulting WAR file:

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                        <Build-Host>${agent.name}</Build-Host>
                        <Build-User>${user.name}</Build-User>
                        <Build-Maven>Maven ${maven.version}</Build-Maven>
                        <Build-Java>${java.version}</Build-Java>
                        <Build-OS>${os.name}</Build-OS>
                        <Build-Label>${project.version}</Build-Label>
                        <Build-Path>${basedir}</Build-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
...
</build>
```

The MANIFEST.MF that is created looks correct see below apart from the Build-Maven line in which the ${maven.version} is not substituted with the actual version number 3.0.4 in this case.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: stocjon
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Build-Host: 
Build-Java: 1.6.0_35
Build-Label: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Build-Maven: Maven ${maven.version}
Build-OS: Windows XP
Build-Path: C:\Development\project_name
Build-Time: 15:38:50 21-Sep-2012
Build-User: user_name
```

Any ideas why Maven version is not being populated in the MANIFEST.MF ?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>maven-version</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Check [here](http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/howto-add-the-maven-version-number-to-the-manifest-mf-file/) for details.

Comment: Both answers point to the same Blog post.  Accepted the first one.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Another question, how do I get the build host ie the machine name of the computer which carried out the build.  ${agent.name} doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try this: <Build-Machine>${env.COMPUTERNAME}</Build-Machine>, this works for me.

Answer (score 7):

We no more need the **build-helper-maven-plugin** since the feature ([MSHARED-38](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED-38)) was added to the component **maven-archiver : 2.5** in Feb. 2012 ([release notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED/fixforversion/17630)).

And this component is used by the Maven plugins like *maven-jar-plugin*, *maven-war-plugin*, *maven-ear-plugin*, etc.

The versions of these plugins using this feature are :

- maven-jar-plugin : **2.4** ([MJAR-148](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-148)), released in Feb. 2012
- maven-war-plugin : **2.2** ([MWAR-273](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-273)), released in Feb. 2012
- maven-ear-plugin : **2.8** ([MEAR-145](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEAR-145)), released in Sept. 2012
- maven-assembly-plugin : **2.4** ([MASSEMBLY-634](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-634)), released in Nov. 2012
- maven-ejb-plugin : **2.4** ([MEJB-56](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEJB-56)), EDIT : released on 24/Aug/14
- etc.

So now we'll have this entry by default in the archive's manifest.mf :

> Created-By: Apache Maven ${maven.version}

Answer (score 5):

At least as of version 2.4 of the maven-jar plugin, the following entries are added by default to the MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF in the jar:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
 Built-By: abcUser
 Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
 Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77
```

To add the project version and other implementation details, simply add the following to the maven-jar-plugin (either in the pluginManagement section or in the build -> plugins section:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
         <archive>
             <manifest>
                 <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
             </manifest>

         </archive>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

To add something like a build time, add the following:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
         <archive>
             <manifest>
                 <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
             </manifest>
             <manifestEntries>
                 <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>                            
             </manifestEntries>
         </archive>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The Build-Time format can be changed by using the following property in the `<properties>` section of your pom.xml:

```
<maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
```

The output of all the above is something like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: UI
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: abcUser
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.xyz.abc.dbe
Build-Time: 2016-12-23 12:04 UTC
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77
Implementation-Vendor: XYZ Corporation
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness - this worked for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This puts in my manifest -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Old.Curmudgeon
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22
Implementation-Title: JarFileName-1.0.2
Implementation-Version: 1.0.2
Implementation-Vendor-Id: our.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the build machine I added the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>project.properties["hostname"] = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()</source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I could then retrieve the host machine name through ${hostname}.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look how it's suggested by `jcabi-manifests`: http://manifests.jcabi.com/versioning.html

Also, see this blog post for more details: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html